# how to initialize a 3d array of Vectors3 in Unity

Tags: unity, voxels

I scoured the web for how to create a 3d array of Vectors to store chunks location info for a Voxel terrain generation based on Craig Perko's Terrain generation on YouTube. I was also using lists and dictionaries in the past but I want to try with arrays now. I already declare a 3d byte array for the blocks Inside chunks. But I got no clue on how to create a Vector3 3d array or byte 3d array to hold the chunks positions in space. So any help on how to create a 3d array of vectors3 from a loop of Positions is greatly appreciated. I am quite new and noOb so sorry if this doesnt make any sense.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 2; z++)
        {
            Vector3[,,] = new Vector3[,,]
            {
                {
                    {
                        new Vector3[x,y,z]
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that code even compile? Because it doesn't really make any sense at all. Also, if you reference some video in your question, please post a link. You can not assume that your readers have watched every single game development tutorial ever posted on YouTube.

Comment: Don't you want to just create a 3D array that translates to 3D positions? Like `Block[100, 100, 100]` would create a 100x100x100 array of blocks? And if you have the vector in 3D space of a specific block you can access it by `block[v.x, v.y, v.z]`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are going to achieve with this, probably because I never did anything with voxels.

But you can create and initialize your 3d array like this:

```
var xSize = 2;
var ySize = 2;
var zSize = 2;

Vector3[,,] myVectors = new Vector3[xSize,ySize,zSize];
for (int z = 0; z < zSize; z++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < ySize; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < xSize; x++)
        {
            myVectors[x,y,z] = new Vector3();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @doppelgreener: Thanks for the edit. I mindlessly took those magic numbers from the question.

Comment: thank you all for your responses! I will go with Morothar's answer here on how to create a 3d array of Vector3's. I am very sorry for the noObie question!